# Rosa's theorem about tree T with m edges to decompose a complete with 2m+1 vertice

Tags: graph-theory

In this theorem
Rosa tell us that if there exist a tree T is graceful with m edges, then K_2m+1 could be decomposed into 2m+1 copies of tree T.

But I want to ask that should the 2m+1 copies be graceful?

Because I have seen some slide about it

[the slide about decomposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5jZ7.png)

Some of copies satisfy this property but some of don't

Comment: I would say not necessarily

Comment: They do not have to be graceful with the labeling inherited from the clique. They are of course graceful with their original labeling.

Comment: So theses copies are just isomorphic to the tree T, right?

Comment: "They are of course graceful with their original labeling." 
This comment means that the original tree T?